# Dynamically reference an import

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

In **Ecmascript 6**, how can I instantiate a class from an imported module with a variable?

```
Ex: import MyModule from './modules/moduleName';
let myVar = "MyModule";
let foo = new window[myVar]( params );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a mapping containing all imported modules you want to dynamically instantiate. E.g.

```
var classes = {
  MyModule,
};
```

Then you can do

```
new classes[myVar]();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are exporting the class you shoud just instantiate as if it was a simple object so

```
let myVar = new MyModule();
```

hope it helps

Comment: But my problem is that the "MyModule" part need to be a variable.

Comment: you mean you dont have to create an instance there, but elsewere?

Comment: I mean, I will import a lot of modules, but I will receive a list of modules to creates in an array. So I need to create a new {Something}() with   {Something} being a variable.